# jQuery UI Accordion focus on opened item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having the problem where if there is a lot of text in one of the accordion parts when opening the next part (and collapsing the open part) the scroll position is way off. Help?

https://jsfiddle.net/3u08r242/1/

```
 $(function() {
   $(".accordian")
     .accordion({
       heightStyle: "content",
       collapsible: true,
       active: false
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`activate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate)** method, to `scroll` to the position where `header` is present, once the `panel` is opened.

```
activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $('html,body').scrollTop($(ui.newHeader).offset().top)
}
```

## [`DEMO HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3u08r242/3/)

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work when I applied to my full code but pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using:

```
activate: function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.newHeader).get(0).scrollIntoView();
}
```

## [`DEMO HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3u08r242/4/)

Answer (score 1):

These two answers are fine. I'd consider animating it with:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(ui.newHeader).offset().top},'slow');
```

I've got a more complicated solution that allows animation to happen at the same time as the panel opens.

I store the locations of the scrolltops that I want when the accordion is first opened, then use the beforeActivate method to scroll. Here's the code:

```
var accordionTops = {};

$(function() {
   $(".accordian")
     .accordion({
       heightStyle: "content",
       collapsible: true,
       active: false,
       beforeActivate: function( event, ui ){
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui);
        // only trigger on opening a panel
        if (ui.newHeader.hasOwnProperty(0)){
           var myId = ui.newHeader[0].id;
           $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: accordionTops[myId]},'slow');
         }

       },
       activate:function( event, ui ){
         setAccordionTops($(this).parent());
       }
     });

 });

 function setAccordionTops(parent){
  $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
  // store hilight section tops for use in hilights animation
  $('h3.ui-accordion-header', parent).each(function(){
    var myId = $(this).attr('id')
    if (!(accordionTops.hasOwnProperty(myId))){
      accordionTops[myId] = $(this).offset().top;
    }
  });
}
```

Here's the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rbertolette/ygqdo12n/).